# Refactoring has_many with scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, model-associations

I'm a newbie and I just showed my code to an expert, that told me I shouldn't use `has_many` to filter my variables, but `scopes`.

I have three models : User, Product and Ownership.

So here is my code in **app/models/user.rb** :

```rb
class User
  has_many :ownerships, foreign_key: "offerer_id",
                         dependent: :destroy
  has_many :owned_products, through: :ownerships,
                             source: :product
  has_many :future_ownerships, -> { where owning_date: nil, giving_date: nil },
                               class_name: "Ownership",
                               foreign_key: "offerer_id"
  has_many :wanted_products, through: :future_ownerships,
                             source: :product
end
```

So I deleted the `has_many :future_ownerships` and `has_many :wanted_products`, and created a scope in **app/models/ownership.rb** :

```rb
class Ownership
  scope :future, -> { where owning_date: nil, giving_date: nil }
end
```

Now I can find the future ownerships doing this : `user.ownerships.future`. But what I don't know, is how to retrieve the wanted products ? How can I make a scope in my **app/models/product.rb** to be able to type something like that :

```rb
user.owned_products.wanted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing inherently bad with conditions in your associations, specially if you need to eager load a subset of products.

However to achieve the scope you need, you must add it on the `Product` model and resort to plain sql since the filter is applied on a different model than the one it's defined on.

```
class Product
  # not tested 
  scope :wanted, ->{ where("ownerships.owning_dates IS NULL AND ...") }
end
```

IMHO you're better off with the first solution. The reason is, if for some reason you apply that scope inside a block of many users, you'll hit the O(n) wall despite eager loading the products.

```
User.includes(:owned_products).each do |user|
  user.onwned_products.wanted # => SQL connection
end
```

**Update** :  just found out about `merge` an amazingly [undocumented feature of ActiveRecord](http://blog.mitchcrowe.com/blog/2012/04/14/10-most-underused-activerecord-relation-methods/).

> Among other uses, it allows you to do a join, and filter by a named scope on the joined model

In other words you can do :

```
user.owned_products.merge(Ownership.future)
```

Quit powerful !

Comment: In fact I don't have only one or two `has_many` associations, but two dozens... Is it always good for you ?
Another question, but if I do the scope with plain sql query, will I become sql database dependent ? Anyway, thank you for your advice. :-)

Comment: will I become sql database dependent ? yes but that's very standard sql. The squeel gem can help but it's only compatible with mysql or postres - so no differnece here. re 1st question not quit sure what you mean, it really depends on how you use them - keep both solution and if it clutters your model, put them in a module...

Comment: I just saw your update :-) Do you think I can create a `wanted_products` method in my user model like that ? `def wanted_product` `self.owned_products.merge(Ownership.future)` `end `

Comment: When I do `User.first.owned_products.merge(Ownership.future)` it's working, but not when I do `User.first.wanted_products` with `def wanted_product` `self.owned_products.merge(Ownership.future)` `end`

Comment: I don't see any good reason for that. Is there any error msg ?

Comment: I detailed it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771243/scope-through-associations-joins-and-merge)