# scope through associations : joins and merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, model-associations

I have three models : `User`, `Product` and `Transaction`. 
(`Transaction` belongs_to both, and `User` has many `Product` and `Product` has many `User`, through `Transaction`)

In my `Transaction` model, I have a scope for `current` transactions :

```rb
scope :current, -> { where 'transactions.start_date IS NOT NULL AND transactions.end_date IS NULL' }
```

I want to be able to do that in the console, in order to retrieve all the products that have a `current` transaction :

```rb
User.first.products.owned
```

In the console, I can make it happen with :

```rb
User.first.products.merge(Transaction.current.ownership)
```

### First try

So I add this in my `Product` model :

```rb
def self.owned
  merge(Transaction.current.ownership)
end
```

I type that in the console :

```rb
User.first.products.owned
```

But here what's rails console tells me :

```rb
NoMethodError: undefined method `merge' for #<Class:0x00000004e2c0f8>
    from /home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
```

### Other try

If I add this in my `Product` model :

```rb
def self.owned
  joins(:transactions).merge(Transaction.current.ownership)
end
```

I type that in the console :

```rb
User.first.products.owned
```

But it retrieve all products with a current transaction, and not only the first user's products with a current transaction.

Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Really don't think it'll work but try out : `scoped.merge(Transaction.current.ownership)` Otherwise I'm afraid you're stuck with `merge` but you can shorten the argument you're sending it.

Comment: I tried that and it returns `DEPRECATION WARNING: Model.scoped is deprecated. Please use Model.all instead.` So I did `all.merge(Transaction.current.ownership)` and then it worked ! Thank you ! Do you want to answer properly to my question, in order to validate it for future viewers ?

Comment: ok happy it worked I was afraid scoped aka all wouldn't hold on the user scope - are you sure it does ? Anyway did wrote the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of cause you just didnt oder or limit your products.

```
scope :current, where('transactions.start_date IS NOT NULL AND transactions.end_date IS NULL').order("by whatever").limit(1)
```

You may need to order it the right product is selected if not you can remove the order method.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work :-( Here the error message after doing what you proposed : `User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]`
`NoMethodError: undefined method `limit' for <Proc:0x00000001fe7b20>`

Answer (score 2):

1. **First try** : you're calling `merge` on a `Product` but `merge` I believe needs to be called explicitly on an `AR::Relation` unlike `where`, `joins` & so on.
2. **Second try** : the `joins` is messing up the User scope.

I suggest you use the method `scoped` (for rails < 4) or `all` (for rails >= 4) which will proxy an AR::Relation needed for the method `merge` to function.

```
def self.owned
  scoped.merge(Transaction.current.ownership)
end
```