# Multiple conditions for has_many relationship in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm updating a legacy Rails 2.0 application and found this code which seems to not work for Rails 4 anymore...:

**company.rb:**

```
has_many :orders
has_many :pending_orders,
    :class_name => "Order",
    :conditions => "(orders.coworker_id IS NULL OR orders.delivery_time IS NULL) AND orders.finished_at IS NULL",
    :order => "orders.created_at ASC"
```

The docs aren't very comprehensive in this case, so I'm looking out for the right solution to update this code to Rails 4 syntax. This is my attempt, but I'm not sure if this is the right solution:

```
has_many :pending_orders, -> { (where(orders: {coworker_id: nil}) || where(orders: {delivery_time: nil})) && where(orders: {finished_at: nil}) }, class_name: "Order"
```

Comment: Did it worked or it didn't?

Comment: It doesn't show an error but I'm not sure if I'm getting the right data. I'm testing at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your attempt doesn't work,try giving like this

```
has_many :pending_orders, -> { where(orders.coworker_id IS NULL OR orders.delivery_time IS NULL) And orders.finished_at IS NULL }, class_name: "Order"
```

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443224/refactoring-has-many-with-scopes)**

Comment: I get " Unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting '}' " when I try to put an And or Or to chain multiple conditions.